# I am trying to make a background, but the sky emits a light and tints the rest of my scene. How do I prevent this?

Tags: node-editor

[image]

I just want a solid color background. You don't need to actively say the answer, maybe just link me to a video with the answer.

Comment: Hello :). Your world background will *always* affect your scene. To remove the color tint, use a background with zero color saturation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. world properties, surface, Strenght = 0
2. Render properties, Film, check "transparent"
3. Compositing tab, check "use nodes", mix the render output with solid color (mixing it with the alpha channel of the render layers node) --> see image (you have to mix the render with a solid color and use as factor the alpha layer of the render)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I cant find render properties/film though. One place says i have to be in cycles. Is render properties the orange box?

Comment: check this (evee and cycles)
https://i.imgur.com/oRklmse.png

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but it isn't working so far. Here is what I'm doing https://imgur.com/a/ec0TjeZ

Comment: that's the node setup for the post compositing process:
https://i.imgur.com/MFpqKiV.png

Comment: Please don't ask users to accept an answer unless they have indicated in the comments that the answer has solved their issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a node-based solution:

Normal usage. As you can see the blue sky tints all surfaces
[image: Without light path node]

Using the Light Path node. The sky is still blue but it becomes invisible to all except the camera
[image: With the light path node]